# Is it possible to drawing spectogram using python with array(hand point) value?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, pyqtgraph, pose-estimation

I have array values that extract hand point by pose estimation model.

With that array value, I want to express the spectogram in one graph for each key point value of the hand.

Like this,

[image: Example 1)]

[image: Example 2)]

How can i make it?

Please, give me direction

Comment: Have you checked https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#polygon-plots?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question so that others can help you with it. :)

Comment: @medium-dimensional oh, i know that reference, but i wanna real-time spectogram like waving. I'm not good at coding, so i wanna ask u guys if u know that reference code using custom dataset and guide..